# Porque não posso remover um downvote imediatamente?

Tags: suporte, voto-contra

Aconteceu algumas vezes de eu dar um downvote e depois através de algum comentário, de alguma pesquisa que estou fazendo em relação à pergunta, ou mesmo de refletir melhor,  acabar vendo que o downvote não foi adequado. Procuro remover o downvote, mas a interface do site não permite até que a pergunta/resposta seja editada. Essa forma de funcionamento está correta? Por quê?

Comment: Agora não tenho tempo para fazer uma resposta, mas sim é o funcionamento correto do site. Tente analisar melhor as perguntas/respostas antes de votar. Só tem lógica mudar um voto nosso se a pergunta for editada, se ela mudar, não acha?

Comment: Não é tanto o caso de analisar melhor. É que quando outro usuário comenta pode dar um perspectiva que antes vc não tem. Outra coisa é que às vezes a gente procura auxiliar no site enquanto estamos trabalhando, por exemplo, enquanto esperamos um processo demorado ou algo assim e muitas vezes não temos 1/2 hora pra ficar analisando um pergunta. Mais do que isso, todos nós comentemos erros e deveríamos ter o poder de pedir desculpas e retirar o que dissemos. :)

Comment: Então o ideal, quando a pergunta parece "estranha" para você é questionar o OP antes de dar um voto. Alias, é o que os mais veteranos costumam recomendar: "Primeiro questione, depois vote."

Comment: @JorgeB. É o funcionamento atual do site. Agora, se é o correto ou não, é discutível. Concordo com vc e com o colega Diego, de que o ideal é comentar antes de votar. Mas, o voto é uma prerrogativa do usuário (isto é, cada um vota como quiser). Por que a retirada dele não é? Pra mim faz pouco sentido e parece uma tentativa de limitar usos ruins (no "jogo" pela reputação, por exemplo) que acaba atrapalhando mais o comportamento honesto do que impedindo algo pouco nocivo.

Comment: @LuizVieira não concordo, se os votos pudessem ser alterados era uma confusão, andava tudo a tirar e a por votos à toa. Podes acreditar nisso. E depois choviam notificações de votos a toda a hora, nem é bom pensar. Eu raramente precisei de alterar um voto sem edição da publicação e tenho 1531 votos, não me parece que seja assim tão significativo.

Comment: Eu entendo a motivação porque é assim, mas não concordo com ela. Também não acho que tenha solução boa.

Comment: @JorgeB. Você não acha que faz mais sentido o sistema demorar mais pra mandar as notificações do que simplesmente impedir de retirar os votos? Eu também raramente senti essa necessidade, mas já ocorreu ao menos umas 3 vezes. O fato de ser raro não quer dizer que o sistema esteja correto. :)

Comment: Pra mim parece que esse caos caso se liberasse a remoção de downvotes é mais presumido que real. Se fosse assim tbem não se deveria poder remover comentários ou respostas pq elas geraram notificação.

Comment: Exatamente @NelsonTeixeira!

Comment: @LuizVieira mas para corrigir a excepção ias estragar a regra. Eu acho que como esta é a melhor solução que conheço. Vocês estão a insistir nas notificações, mas esse não é o problema, o problema é que as pessoas não se sabem comportar e os votos viravam galhofa em vez de distinguir o conteúdo do site como bom ou mau.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu também não acho que é o problema, mas foi você quem usou as notificações como argumento, meu caro. :) Pra mim o problema na verdade são dois: a escolha e o entendimento. Eu não tenho a escolha de remover conforme eu julgar, e eu não entendo completamente a motivação por trás desse mecanismo.

Comment: @LuizVieira eu acho que a ideia do mecanismo é "obrigar" (ou tentar) as pessoas a votar com consciência, sabendo que não podem alterar o seu voto. E eu, pessoalmente, acho que funciona. Esses raros casos de querer mudar o voto são um mal pequeno. Acho que assim temos mais garantias da fiabilidade do voto. Pelo menos é assim que eu penso. Mas para esclarecer só um moderador ou o Gabe.

Comment: @JorgeB. E, com base no que eu conheço da motivação desse mecanismo hoje, eu discordo que virava galhofa se fosse removido. O sistema é capaz de calcular corretamente as alterações de reputação de todos os envolvidos e as notificações podem ser agrupadas. As pessoas já votam como bem entendem (para o bem ou para o mal), e retirar o voto teria (na minha opinião) o mesmo impacto. Não acho que o sistema vá ser alterado, mas seria bacana entendermos bem a motivação disso. A pergunta aqui é justa. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira não sei, mas a mim parece-me que ia ser uma desgraça... Mas só vendo...

Comment: @JorgeB. Entendo. Talvez essa seja parte da motivação. Mas "votar com consciência" é algo bastante subjetivo, e nesse sentido eu acho que a penalidade por votar negativo é mais eficiente do que a percepção de que o voto não pode ser removido. Vc pode ter razão, podem ser casos raros *hoje*, mas talvez as pessoas votassem mais se pudessem retirar os votos como quisessem, o que ajudaria mais a filtrar o conteúdo. :)

Comment: Talvez, mas não me parece ;)

Comment: A meu ver tudo se resume a uma questão mais humana: somos falíveis, podemos prejudicar alguém por um erro nosso e assim como na vida existe a desculpa e a compensação em alguns casos, tbém aqui devemos ter a possibilidade de minimizar nossos erros.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## TL;DR

Votos positivos ou negativos são "travados" após uma janela de 5 minutos, então não é possível mais alterar a não ser que a pergunta ou resposta seja editada.

## Motivação

[Motivo "oficial" pelo Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80763/262149):

> This helps to prevent irregularities in voting. If I could go back and take away every up vote I ever made, more than a few people would see a 1k + drop in reputation. If you thought the post was good, or not good for the duration of the grace period, the system assumes you knew what you were doing when voting either way.

Tradução:

> Isso ajuda a prevenir irregularidades na votação. Se eu pudesse voltar e retirar cada voto positivo que já fiz, várias pessoas veriam uma queda de mais de 1000 pontos na reputação. Se você achou que o conteúdo era bom ou ruim no tempo permitido, o sistema assume que você sabia o que estava fazendo quando votou daquele jeito.

Ele também cita uma fraude conhecida como [*tactical downvoting*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6460/262149) (voto negativo estratégico). Por exemplo, você responde uma pergunta e logo em seguida outra pessoa responde de forma idêntica. Essa pessoa dá um *downvote* na sua resposta, pois ela sabe que as pessoas tendem a votar positivamente nas primeiras respostas e votar negativamente se alguma resposta já tem voto negativo. Depois de algum tempo ela retira o voto e faz de conta que nada aconteceu. Claro que tem gente que é cara de pau e nem se preocupa em retirar o voto.

Essa trava do sistema força alguém com más intenções a deixar rastros que os outros usuários e, principalmente a vítima, podem identificar e alertar a moderação.

## O que fazer

Particularmente, eu acho que 5 minutos de carência por pergunta é mais do que suficiente para você ler e reler uma resposta algumas vezes.

Há muitas perguntas todos os dias e, sinceramente, com quantas delas você gasta mais do que 5 minutos?

Também acredito que você deve votar *cedo e frequentemente*. E se, por acaso, você decidir pesquisar mais, **primeiro retire o voto** e depois volte com a sua sentença final.

Claro que nem tudo é perfeito. Já ocorreu de eu dar um voto, ficar com aquilo na cabeça e no outro dia mudar de ideia. Isso ocorreu umas duas vezes em todo meu tempo de SOpt, portanto é mais fácil torcer para o usuário ter editado a resposta ou simplesmente deixar de lado.

Isso leva a outra dica: se você recebeu negativos, sempre edite sua resposta tentando melhorar alguma coisa ou, se não acha que tem erros, acrescente algo a mais, pois isso dá a chance das pessoas reverem os votos.

## Conclusão

Existe uma razão para a trava dos votos após o tempo de 5 minutos de carência.

Se isso mais ajuda ou atrapalha é difícil de afirmar sem  estatísticas reais do quanto as pessoas tentam burlar o sistema e do quanto usuários legitimamente tentam mudar votos.

Porém, tendo ciência do funcionamento, no fim das contas esse limite muito pouco atrapalha pelos motivos que citei no tópico anterior, isto é, desde que você saiba usar o sistema.

Comment: Excelente. Agora compreendi e concordo com o motivo. Grato.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Fiz uma minha a respeito dos pontos discutidos. :)

Answer (score 5):

> TL;DR
>
> **Eu entendo. Aceito também. Mas não concordo.**

Eu tenho quase certeza absoluta que esse mecanismo não vai mudar. Ele também não me incomoda *muito*. Concordo que não é um problema importante. Mas, ainda assim discordo da justificativa e só queria deixar isso registrado aqui.

Com base [na ótima resposta do @utluiz](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5044/73), eu faço alguns comentários a seguir.

A primeira justificativa do mecanismo é essa:

> Isso ajuda a prevenir irregularidades na votação. Se eu pudesse voltar
>   e retirar cada voto positivo que já fiz, várias pessoas veriam uma
>   queda de mais de 1000 pontos na reputação.

Esse cenário de que a retirada dos votos faria outro(s) membro(s) perder(em) 1000 pontos de reputação claramente assume que eu retiraria votos de postagens diferentes *de um mesmo membro* (porque retirar um único voto de uma postagem qualquer ou vários votos de postagens de membros diferentes não se traduz em tudo isso de perda de reputação). Essa *irregularidade*, como foi chamada, poderia ser detectada e coibida de outra forma. A retirada sequencial de votos em postagens de um mesmo membro (que não precisa ser em intervalos curtos de tempo) poderia ser detectada pelo sistema para que aquele usuário fosse devidamente punido.

O quão fácil é implementar isso no sistema *é outra discussão*. Talvez tenha realmente sido mais simples e direto implementar a limitação da remoção do voto. Mas é importante ficar claro pra todo mundo que essa é *uma escolha de design* da equipe do SE, e que isso não necessariamente se traduz em melhor usabilidade para a comunidade.

A segunda justificativa (que era a que eu supunha existir) é essa:

> Ele também cita uma fraude conhecida como tactical downvoting (voto
>   negativo estratégico). Por exemplo, você responde uma pergunta e logo
>   em seguida outra pessoa responde de forma idêntica. Essa pessoa dá um
>   downvote na sua resposta, pois ela sabe que as pessoas tendem a votar
>   positivamente nas primeiras respostas e votar negativamente se alguma
>   resposta já tem voto negativo. Depois de algum tempo ela retira o voto
>   e faz de conta que nada aconteceu. Claro que tem gente que é cara de
>   pau e nem se preocupa em retirar o voto.

O problema está justamente no "Claro que tem gente que é cara de pau e nem se preocupa em retirar o voto". Partindo do princípio de que o voto é uma prerrogativa de cada indivíduo, o que verdadeiramente coibe esse comportamento é o custo em votar e não a impossibilidade de retirar o voto. Do jeito que é hoje, esse tactical downvoting já acontece: basta fazer exatamente o mesmo e não se importar em retirar o voto. Quem, além dos moderadores, pode te acusar de ser o votante?

Além do mais, mesmo em um cenário (utópico, infelizmente) de que a remoção de votos fosse possível, um usuário que suspeitasse sofrer desse tipo de ataque poderia requisitar a análise *da mesma forma como faz hoje*. A remoção do voto não significa necessariamente a eliminação de rastros, já que da mesma forma que o sistema guarda o voto e quem votou ele poderia guardar a última ação (voto dado/retirado) de quem votou.

**Concluindo...**

Na prática, todos que são a favor do comportamento do sistema como é hoje argumentam que as ocorrências de problemas nesse formato são pequenas - e por isso devemos conviver com elas. É fato que a ocorrência de problemas são pequenas. Mas seria interessante analisar com cuidado (mesmo sem implementar nada) se a ocorrência desses problemas de irregularidade e downvoting estratégico não seriam igualmente pequenas no cenário alternativo de permissão de retirada de downvotes. Se as ocorrências forem igualmente poucas, mas a usabilidade para a comunidade melhorar, talvez valha o esforço.

O downvoting estratégico me parece muito mais relevante do que a tal "irregularidade", mas ambos poderiam ser coibidos com ações sistêmicas para auditoria (detectar sequências de downvotes em posts de um mesmo autor e armazenar última ação na postagem mesmo após a retirada do voto). Se a decisão for por não fazer nada porque vai dar trabalho de analisar, discutir ou mesmo implementar, é justo ao menos deixar isso claro.

P.S.: Perdoem pela chatice. Juro que não faço por mal. rs

Comment: sobre chatice... http://www.alemdoobvio.com/?p=109  fiz meu comercial ;)

Comment: Note que eu não disse em nenhum momento que concordo. Para mim isto é mais uma regra legada que fez sentido num contexto e numa época. Posso estar errado. :P

Comment: Notado e anotado @utluiz. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira exceto pelo fato de que nem os moderadores podem ver os votos, está tudo perfeito. Se existisse uma mínima chance de mudar alguma coisa, poderíamos discutir, procurar alternativas, ver o que mais precisaria mudar (talvez obrigar a justificativa da mudança de voto - pública ou privada p/ os moderadores), achar soluções p/ o problema ao invés de simplesmente dizer que não funciona. Mas é melhor nem perder tempo e seguir com essa usabilidade.

Comment: @bigown Obrigado pela informação. Eu realmente a desconhecia - imaginava que a informação de votos era disponível para moderadores para fins de auditoria (quando solicitado).

Comment: @LuizVieira eles acessam estatísticas para ver padrões de voto, mas não votos individuais. Os funcionários da SE podem ver tudo.