# Por que o voto negativo desconta 2 pontos de reputação?

Tags: suporte, voto-contra

Por que quando você vota negativamente em uma pergunta ou resposta você perde dois pontos de reputação depois de um curto tempo?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Porque não posso remover um downvote imediatamente?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5041/porque-n%c3%a3o-posso-remover-um-downvote-imediatamente)

Comment: [Não é bem assim que funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você não perde dois pontos quando dá um voto negativo. Você perde dois pontos quando recebe um voto negativo. Conforme indicado pelo bfavaretto: [O que é reputação? Como faço para ganhar (ou perder) pontos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Dar votos negativos não lhe custa nada em perguntas, mas custa um ponto para respostas. O motivo é que [respostas são mais valiosas do que perguntas](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/19/important-reputation-rule-changes/).

Esse valor de um ponto ao se negativar respostas é irrisório, mas tem um efeito psicológico: como tem muita gente que se apega muito ao escore (vendo a pontuação como causa ao invés de consequência), isso faz com que os usuários em geral pensem duas vezes antes de dar um voto negativo. Todo voto deveria exigir um mínimo de reflexão, já que se trata de um julgamento.

Outro efeito do valor negativo da votação negativa em respostas é que assim evitamos o *tactical downvoting*, que é quando alguém negativa as respostas de outras pessoas sem motivo para que suas próprias respostas apareçam em destaque.

Por fim: [Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2632/1658)